# Can I add files to GitHub directly from a URL without downloading them first?

Tags: github

I'm looking to add files straight from the internet to my GitHub repo without downloading them first. Is that doable?
Like, I want to grab a file from "www.example.com/file1" and put it right into GitHub without saving it on my computer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't offer a way to just check in files from arbitrary locations on the Internet.  First of all, that's not very secure, since you don't know that the URL hasn't changed from the time you inspected it to the time that GitHub would have picked it up.  In addition, downloading the file is typically not a very big burden.

However, GitHub's API does offer a way to [create or update file contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents).  You could write a program that downloads the file content, verifies it according to whatever rules you want, and then uploads it directly to GitHub, all without saving it to disk.  Note that this is only the case for small files, since beyond a certain size, the API can't be used.

If the file is large (I think bigger than 10 MiB), then you have to clone the repository, add it using Git, and then upload.  If you want to minimize the amount of work to clone, you can use a shallow clone (`git clone --depth=1`).